# HTML / PHP / SQL How to display a button under certain circumstances?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So I have a script using HTML, PHP, and mysql, and I want to display a button under certain circumstances.
Here is my script:

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $q = $_GET['query']; 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE `id` LIKE '%$q%'"); 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count != "1"){
        $output = '<h2>No result found!</h2>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $s = $row['name'];
                $output .= '<h2>Found: '.$s.'</h2><br>';
            }
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="index.html">
            <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">
        </form>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Specifically, I want to display the return button only when the output is  "No results found", when the amount of rows in the SQL database matching the given query is not 1. How could I go about accomplishing this? I'm relatively new to PHP and mySQLi, but from my research I couldn't figure out how to do such a task, any ideas?

Comment: by using a simple php `if` statement, which you can do inside `<?php ?>` in the html bit of your code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a much cleaner html code, do this:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.html">
    <?php if ($count!= "1") : ?>
    <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">
    <?php else : ?>
    <!-- put your other button here -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

You can read more about escaping from HTML [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
if ($count==0) {
 echo '<input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include_once('dbconnect.php');
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $q = $_GET['query']; 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE `id` LIKE '%$q%'"); 
    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="index.html">
            <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">
        </form>
        <?php if(0 < count($results)) ?>
        <?php foreach($results AS $row) : ?>
        <h2><?= $row['name'] ?></h2>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <H2> No results found!</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```